# Using twbs:bootstrap on Meteor?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

So I installed the package to meteor but now how to I use it in the code. I keep on getting errors when I run 'meteor'. It keeps telling me that I need jquery and all this other stuff. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Do I need to import the package and then wrapper all of the html in my in a bootstrap method like this? :

```
bootstrap(
   <h1>Hello World</h1>
);
```

Comment: try adding jquery package `meteor add jquery`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure there is jquery packages loaded before twbs:bootstrap inside package file in .meteor folder. but the error shouldn't occur since twbs:bootstrap depends in jquery in package.js file
package.js file

```
Package.describe({
 name: 'twbs:bootstrap',  // http://atmospherejs.com/twbs/bootstrap
 summary: 'The most popular front-end framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.',
version: '3.3.6',
git: 'https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git'
```

});

```
 Package.onUse(function (api) {
 api.versionsFrom('METEOR@1.0');
api.use('jquery', 'client');
 var assets = [
  'dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot',
  'dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg',
'dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf',
'dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff',
'dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2'
 ];
if (api.addAssets) {
  api.addAssets(assets, 'client');
 } else {
api.addFiles(assets, 'client', { isAsset: true });
}
api.addFiles([
'dist/css/bootstrap.css',
'dist/js/bootstrap.js'
  ], 'client');
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized that I forgot to delete the source files from the actual bootstrap site. So when I deleted those it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can add bootstrap by running the following command in cmd/terminal :

```
meteor add twbs:bootstrap
```

This should solve the problem.
You can add version using following :

```
meteor add twbs:bootstrap@3.3.6
```

This adds the relevant dependencies(like jquery) automatically.